# constraint to avoid generating duplicates in this search task

Tags: search, optimization, duplicates, utility, a-star

I have to solve the following optimization problem:
Given a set of elements (E1,E2,E3,E4,E5,E6) create an arbitrary set of sequences e.g.

```
seq1:E1,E4,E3
seq2:E2
seq3:E6,E5
```

and given a function f that gives a value for every pair of elements e.g.

```
f(E1,E4) = 5
f(E4,E3) = 2
f(E6,E5) = 3
...
```

in addition it also gives a value for the pair of an element combined with some special element T, e.g.

```
f(T,E2) = 10
f(E2,T) = 3
f(E5,T) = 1
f(T,E6) = 2
f(T,E1) = 4
f(E3,T) = 2
...
```

The utility function that must be optimized is the following:
The utility of a sequence set is the sum of the utility of all sequences.
The utility of a sequence A1,A2,A3,...,AN is equal to
f(T,A1)+f(A1,A2)+f(A2,A3)+...+f(AN,T)
for our example set of sequences above this leads to

```
seq1: f(T,E1)+f(E1,E4)+f(E4,E3)+f(E3,T) = 4+5+2+2=13
seq2: f(T,E2)+f(E2,T) =10+3=13
seq3: f(T,E6)+f(E6,E5)+f(E5,T) =2+3+1=6
Utility(set) = 13+13+6=32
```

I try to solve a larger version (more elements than 6, rather 1000) of this problem using A* and some heuristic. Starting from zero sequences and stepwise adding elements either to existing sequences or as a new sequence, until we obtain a set of sequences containing all elements.
The problem I run into is the fact that while generating possible solutions I end up with duplicates, for example in above example all the following combinations are generated:

```
seq1:E1,E4,E3
seq2:E2
seq3:E6,E5
+
seq1:E1,E4,E3
seq2:E6,E5
seq3:E2
+
seq1:E2
seq2:E1,E4,E3
seq3:E6,E5
+
seq1:E2
seq2:E6,E5
seq3:E1,E4,E3
+
seq1:E6,E5
seq2:E2
seq3:E1,E4,E3
+
seq1:E6,E5
seq2:E1,E4,E3
seq3:E2
```

which all have equal utility, since the order of the sequences does not matter.
These are all permutations of the 3 sequences, since the number of sequences is arbitrairy there can be as much sequences as elements and a faculty(!) amount of duplicates generated...
One way to solve such a problem is keeping already visited states and don't revisit them. However since storing all visited states requires a huge amount of memory and the fact that comparing two states can be a quite expensive operation, I was wondering whether there wasn't a way I could avoid generating these in the first place.

**THE QUESTION:**
Is there a way to stepwise construct all these sequence constraining the adding of elements in a way that only combinations of sequences are generated rather than all variations of sequences.(or limit the number of duplicates)

As an example, I only found a way to limit the amount of 'duplicates' generated by stating that an element Ei should always be in a seqj with j<=i, therefore if you had two elements E1,E2 only

```
seq1:E1
seq2:E2
```

would be generated, and not

```
seq1:E2
seq2:E1
```

I was wondering whether there was any such constraint that would prevent duplicates from being generated at all, without failing to generate all combinations of sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it is simple. Allow generation of only such sequences that are sorted according to first member, that is, from the above example, only

```
seq1:E1,E4,E3
seq2:E2
seq3:E6,E5
```

would be correct. And this you can guard very easily: never allow additional sequence that has its first member less than the first member of its predecessor.

Comment: very nice solution! Simplicity is the ultimate sophistication! My most sincere thanks.